# PostgeSQL create tab

Tags: python, postgresql

There is an entry for creating a database:

```
create table stack.Accounts
(
   row_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ,
   parent_id int,                         -- row_id родительской записи
   number int,                            -- Номер лицевого счета
   type int,                              -- Тип записи (1 - Дом, 2- Квартира, 3 - Лицевой счет)

   constraint PK_Accounts
      primary key (row_id),
   constraint FK_Accounts_Folder 
      foreign key (parent_id) 
      references stack.Accounts(row_id)
      on delete no action
      on update no action
);
```

but I don't understand what "stack" means?

I didn't find any help information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stack is a so called schema. With `create table stack.Accounts` you are creating a table in the schema stack.

More inforamtion about schma can be found here for example [psql docs schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html)